# LP Optimization with PulP. Using IF to set up constraints

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex, pulp

Looking for a way to set up a constraint of my optimization problem using an IF ELSE function. It boils down to this: if constant A is smaller than variable B, then variable D=0, else D=A-B. Here's [a clear formulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm9mx.jpg).

I get the error

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'LpVariable'
```

Is there a way to circumvent this?

My python script is shown below:

```
import pulp
import random

# setting up constants
t_0=1000
A=[]
for x in range(t_0):
    A.append(random.randint(1,10))


# initializing LP
LP = pulp.LpProblem('LP',pulp.LpMinimize)  

# adding variables
B = pulp.LpVariable("B", cat='Continuous', lowBound=0)  
D = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("D", range(t_0), cat=pulp.LpContinuous, lowBound=0)

# adding constraints
for t in range(t_0):

    if A[t] > B:
        LP += D[t]  == A[t] - B
    else:
        LP += D[t] == 0


LP += pulp.lpSum(D[t] for t in range(t_0)) 


status = LP.solve(pulp.CPLEX_PY(mip=True, msg=True, timeLimit=15,epgap=None))

print( 'LP status: ' + pulp.LpStatus[status] + '')
```

Comment: why dont you solve it without linear programming? Would be much faster

Comment: LP/MIP models deal with linear equalities and in-equalities (<= and >=). So no `if` allowed in a constraint, and also no strict inequalities (< and >).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know PULP but what you are looking for are "indicator constraints" in CPLEX. Check the PULP documentation whether and how it supports indicator or logical constraints.

But there also is another option: Your problem is

```
minimize sum D(t)
D(t) = A(t)-B if A(t) > B
D(t) = 0 if A(t) <= B
```

Since this attempts to minimize `D(t)`, in any optimal solution `D(t)` will be as small as possible. So you can replace your constraints by

```
D(t) >= A(t) - B
D(t) >= 0
```

If `B >= A(t)` then the first one will be trivially satisfied and the second one together with the objective sense will set `D(t) = 0`. Similarly, if `B < A(t)` then the second one will be trivially satisfied and the first one together with the objective sense will set `D(t) = A(t) - B`.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to find the equivalent of "if_then" that you have in docplex API

For instance

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
   print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print()
print("with if nb buses 40 more than 3  then nbBuses30 more than 7")

mdl.add(mdl.if_then((nbbus40>=3),(nbbus30>=7)))
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

gives

```
nbBus40  =  6.0
nbBus30  =  2.0

with if nb buses 40 more than 3  then nbBuses30 more than 7
nbBus40  =  0
nbBus30  =  10.0
```

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62195169/15893581) in Pulp with CPLEX Solver